# Strange behaviour of int inside a struct

Tags: go, atomic, uint32

Let's say we have this kind of a struct (one of the simplest ever):

```
type some struct{
    I uint32
}
```

And we want to have a variable of that type and to atomically increment in for loop (possibly in another goroutine but now the story is different). I do the following:

```
q := some{0}
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        atomic.AddUint32(&q.I,1) // increment [1]
        fmt.Println(q.I)
}
```

We're getting what we'd expect, so far so good, but if we declare a function for that type as follows:

```
func (sm some) Add1(){
    atomic.AddUint32(&sm.I,1)
}
```

and call this function in the above sample (line [1]) the value isn't incremented and  we just get zeros. The question is obvious - why?

This has to be something basic but since I am new to go I don't realize it.

Comment: Tha approach  to pointers of the Go language is a bit confusing. In Go, you define a method receiver to specify which struct to attach a certain function to in order to make it invoke-able as a method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Calls](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls)
>
> In a function call, the function value and arguments are evaluated in
>   the usual order. After they are evaluated, the parameters of the call
>   are passed by value to the function and the called function begins
>   execution. The return parameters of the function are passed by value
>   back to the calling function when the function returns.

The receiver `sm some` is passed by value to the method and the copy is discarded when you return from the method. Use a pointer receiver.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync/atomic"
)

type some struct {
    I uint32
}

func (sm *some) Add1() {
    atomic.AddUint32(&sm.I, 1)
}

func main() {
    var s some
    s.Add1()
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Output:

```
{1}
```

> [Go Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](https://golang.org/doc/faq)
>
> [When are function parameters passed by value?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#pass_by_value)
>
> As in all languages in the C family, everything in Go is passed by
>   value. That is, a function always gets a copy of the thing being
>   passed, as if there were an assignment statement assigning the value
>   to the parameter. For instance, passing an int value to a function
>   makes a copy of the int, and passing a pointer value makes a copy of
>   the pointer, but not the data it points to.
>
> [Should I define methods on values or pointers?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers)
>
> ```
> func (s *MyStruct) pointerMethod() { } // method on pointer
> func (s MyStruct)  valueMethod()   { } // method on value
> ```
>
> For programmers unaccustomed to pointers, the distinction between
>   these two examples can be confusing, but the situation is actually
>   very simple. When defining a method on a type, the receiver (s in the
>   above examples) behaves exactly as if it were an argument to the
>   method. Whether to define the receiver as a value or as a pointer is
>   the same question, then, as whether a function argument should be a
>   value or a pointer. There are several considerations.
>
> First, and most important, does the method need to modify the
>   receiver? If it does, the receiver must be a pointer. (Slices and maps
>   act as references, so their story is a little more subtle, but for
>   instance to change the length of a slice in a method the receiver must
>   still be a pointer.) In the examples above, if pointerMethod modifies
>   the fields of s, the caller will see those changes, but valueMethod is
>   called with a copy of the caller's argument (that's the definition of
>   passing a value), so changes it makes will be invisible to the caller.
>
> By the way, pointer receivers are identical to the situation in Java,
>   although in Java the pointers are hidden under the covers; it's Go's
>   value receivers that are unusual.
>
> Second is the consideration of efficiency. If the receiver is large, a
>   big struct for instance, it will be much cheaper to use a pointer
>   receiver.
>
> Next is consistency. If some of the methods of the type must have
>   pointer receivers, the rest should too, so the method set is
>   consistent regardless of how the type is used. See the section on
>   method sets for details.
>
> For types such as basic types, slices, and small structs, a value
>   receiver is very cheap so unless the semantics of the method requires
>   a pointer, a value receiver is efficient and clear.

Answer (score 2):

Your function need to receive a pointer for the value to be incremented, that way you are not passing a copy of the struct and on next iteration the I can be incremented.

```
package main

import (
"sync/atomic"
"fmt"
)

type some struct{
    I uint32
}

func main() {
q := &some{0}
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        q.Add1()
        fmt.Println(q.I)
}
}

func (sm *some) Add1(){
    atomic.AddUint32(&sm.I,1)
}
```